# Counting consecutive occurences of an element in pandas dataframe indexed by time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like

```
Date        Race_ID Student_ID  win?
18/10/2023  5       1           0
18/10/2023  5       2           1
17/9/2022   4       1           0
17/9/2022   4       2           1
16/5/2021   3       1           1
16/5/2021   3       2           0
15/4/2020   2       1           1
15/4/2020   2       2           0
14/3/2019   1       1           1
14/3/2019   1       2           0
```

where 1 in `win?` indicates a win and I want to have a new column called `consecutive` which conunts the number of consecutive wins by that student up to that race. So the desired outcome looks like

```
Date        Race_ID Student_ID  win?  consecutive
18/10/2023  5       1           0     0
18/10/2023  5       2           1     1
17/9/2022   4       1           0     3
17/9/2022   4       2           1     0
16/5/2021   3       1           1     2
16/5/2021   3       2           0     0
15/4/2020   2       1           1     1
15/4/2020   2       2           0     0
14/3/2019   1       1           1     0
14/3/2019   1       2           0     0
```

I tried to use groupby and cumcount but I don't know how to handle when the student loses and we have to start over again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, using `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby


def get_consecutive_wins(x):
    c = 0
    for v, g in groupby(x):
        for _ in g:
            yield c
            c = (c + 1) if v else 0


df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=["Student_ID", "Race_ID", "Date"], ascending=[True, True, True])
df["consecutive"] = df.groupby(["Student_ID"])["win?"].transform(get_consecutive_wins)

print(df.sort_index())
```

Prints:

```
        Date  Race_ID  Student_ID  win?  consecutive
0 2023-10-18        5           1     0            0
1 2023-10-18        5           2     1            1
2 2022-09-17        4           1     0            3
3 2022-09-17        4           2     1            0
4 2021-05-16        3           1     1            2
5 2021-05-16        3           2     0            0
6 2020-04-15        2           1     1            1
7 2020-04-15        2           2     0            0
8 2019-03-14        1           1     1            0
9 2019-03-14        1           2     0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution.

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Date')

m = (df2['win?'].eq(0)
     .groupby(df2['Student_ID'])
     .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().mask(x).ffill(limit=1)))

df = (df.assign(
    consecutive  = df2.groupby(['Student_ID',m]).cumcount()
    )
    .fillna({'consecutive':0})
    .astype({'consecutive':'int'}))
```

Output:

```
        Date  Race_ID  Student_ID  win?
0 2023-10-18        5           1     0
1 2023-10-18        5           2     1
2 2022-09-17        4           1     0
3 2022-09-17        4           2     1
4 2021-05-16        3           1     1
5 2021-05-16        3           2     0
6 2020-04-15        2           1     1
7 2020-04-15        2           2     0
8 2019-03-14        1           1     1
9 2019-03-14        1           2     0
```